# how to initialise a javascript variable with nothing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhaviksjoshi91/67sbzxb9/9/)

you can see when I display the content of var it shows undefined at the beginning of the var. How can I initialise a variable with nothing?

Code:

```
<div id='flag'>

</div>

var code;
for(var i=1;i<=10;i++){
    code+="b"+i;
}
console.log(code);
$('#flag').append(code);
```

any help will be appreciated for this topic Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `var code;` declare as `var code = '';`

Comment: actually I was trying with null...so